# Two Angular router-oulets in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-modal, angular-router, angular-routerlink

I have added Other modal in my Angular application both have different

`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Previous one was working fine but after adding 2nd modal with different routes 1st stopped working. i tried with different `name` attributes on router-outlets nothing seems to be working. 
only one is working at a time if i comment out the other one.

```
<button type="button" data-target="#settings2" data-toggle="modal" routerLink="setup_season">                         
   Season
</button>

<button type="button" data-target="#settings" data-toggle="modal" routerLink="setup_package">                         
  Package
</button>
```

first modal

```
 <div id="settings" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

         <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <router-outlet></router-outlet> // already tried with name attribute
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

2nd Modal

```
<div id="settings2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

     <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet> // already tried with name attribute
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide stakblitz reproduction?

Comment: I tried to make stackbkitz but the bootstrap modals were not working in it. So i left it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use auxiliary routes, I will paste a similar case of my own code, try to do the same with your code:

```
  <div class="side-panel">
      <!-- the auxiliary outlet -->
      <router-outlet name="sidePanel"></router-outlet>
  </div>

  <div class="main-content m-0 p-0">
      <!-- the primary outlet -->
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
 </div>
```

The routes configurations should be something similar to this one:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/app/auth/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'app',
    children: [
       {
         path: 'main',
         component: MainComponent
       }, 
       {
         path: 'side-menu',
         component: SlidePanelComponent,
         outlet: 'sidePanel',  // You need to mention the name of the auxiliary route
       }
     ]
]
```

Finally, you need to mention the name of the outlet in the routerLink just like this:

```
  <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { sidePanel: 'side-menu'}}]">
```

Comment: I have 5+ routs on both router outlets. Will work? Because i tried it and they didn't work.

Comment: `[routerLink]="[{ outlets: { sidePanel: 'side-menu'}}]"` This attribute worked for me. I was doing `auxiliary routes` but missing this attribute for routing on my `<a>` tags. Thanks it worked.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib Glad I helped!