# Angular nested Routing in lazy loading Modules with router-outlet name

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing

I am trying to use nested routing together with a named `router-outlet` to accomplish routing for my side-bar navigation.
I have a `main` module that loads the `nav-component` which has a named router-outlet in it's template:

```html
<router-outlet name="content"></router-outlet>
```

Now I have multiple nav-links that use the `router-link` directive to link for example to: `http://localhost:4200/ticket`:

```html
<a routerLink="ticket">New Ticket</a>
```

The routing definition for this module is in the module itself:

```js
#main.module.ts

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: NavComponent, children: [
    { path: 'ticket', component: NewTicketComponent, outlet: 'content' }
  ]},
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [NavComponent, NewCustomerDialogComponent, NewTicketComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ]
})
export class MainModule { }
```

So when you navigate to: `localhost:4200/ticket` I want the `NavComponent` visible and the `NewTicketComponent` to be inserted into the named `router-outlet`

This is what my `app-routing.module.ts` looks like:

```js
#app-routing.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginModule } from './login/login.module';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule) },
  { path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./main/main.module').then(m => m.MainModule) },
  // { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'ticket'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working using nested `router-outlets` without naming them.

I simply made a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` element in my `NavComponent` template. Then I simply defined the nested route like this:

```js
#main.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'main', component: NavComponent, children: [
    { path: 'ticket/new', component: NewTicketComponent}
  ]},
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to mention the name of the outlet in the routerLink just like this:

```
  <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { content: 'main/ticket'}}]">
```

Comment: That did not work :(.
I fixed a typo on the routerLink above as well:
It should be 'ticket' not 'main/ticket'. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Please look at this answer here, it's using edger loading though.https://stackoverflow.com/a/61910213/10121188

Comment: But I did a similar thing into a project I was working with, Along with  mention the name of the outlet, I used loadChildren: 'src/app/modules/seasons/seasons.module#SeasonsModule' , try that and let me know.

Comment: Ty I will take a look. Might have to switch to eager loading.

Comment: Also, try to give a name to the '' route, let it be `nav` so the link will be main\nav\ticket

Comment: Your solution worked, but I found a better one in my opinion and will make a answer for that.